# is there a shorter way to set up queries when filtering results?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have 2 drop down menus where the user can use the drop down menus to filter whih students and questions they wish to see. The possible types of filters are:

- Select All Students and All Questions
- Select All Students and One question
- Select All Questions and one Student
- Select One Student and One Question

Below is drop down menus:

```
<p>
    <strong>Student:</strong>
    <select name="student" id="studentsDrop">
    <option value="All">All</option>
    <?php
    while ( $currentstudentstmt->fetch() ) {
    $stu = $dbStudentId;
    if(isset($_POST["student"]) && $stu == $_POST["student"]) 
        echo "<option selected='selected' value='$stu'>" . $dbStudentAlias . " - " . $dbStudentForename . " " . $dbStudentSurname . "</option>" . PHP_EOL;
    else
        echo "<option value='$stu'>" . $dbStudentAlias . " - " . $dbStudentForename . " " . $dbStudentSurname . "</option>" . PHP_EOL;
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    </p>

    <p>
    <strong>Question:</strong>
    <select name="question" id="questionsDrop">
    <option value="All">All</option>
    <?php
    while ( $questionsstmt->fetch() ) {
    $ques = $dbQuestionId;
    if(isset($_POST["question"]) && $ques == $_POST["question"]) 
        echo "<option selected='selected' value='$ques'>" . $dbQuestionNo . "</option>" . PHP_EOL;
    else
        echo "<option value='$ques'>" . $dbQuestionNo . "</option>" . PHP_EOL;
    }
    ?>
    </select>

</p>
```

Now I want to set up a mysqli query which determines on the students and questions selected from the drop down menu.

My question is simply do I need to set up 4 queries checking for the 4 possibilities I mentioned from the drop down menus or is there are a shorter way?

Do I have to use:

```
 if ($_POST['question'] == 'All' && if ($_POST['student'] == 'All'){){

//NO WHERE CLAUSE

    if ($_POST['question'] == 'All' && if ($_POST['student'] != 'All'){){

//WHERE CLAUSE FOR FINDING SELECTED STUDENT

    if ($_POST['question'] != 'All' && if ($_POST['student'] == 'All'){){

//WHERE CLAUSE FOR FINDING SELECTED QUESTION 

    if ($_POST['question'] != 'All' && if ($_POST['student'] != 'All'){){

//WHERE CLAUSE FOR FINDING SELECTED QUESTION AND SELECTED STUDENT
```

**UPDATE:**

What I have at moment:

```
    function AssessmentIsSubbmitted()
{
    if(isset($_POST['answerSubmit'])) // we have subbmited the first form
    {

//QUERY 1: Student details depending on selected student(s)

if ($_POST['student'] == 'All'){

$selectedstudentqry = "
SELECT
StudentAlias, StudentForename, StudentSurname
FROM Student s
INNER JOIN Student_Session ss ON s.StudentId = ss.StudentId
WHERE SessionId = ?
ORDER BY StudentAlias
";

global $mysqli;
$selectedstudentstmt=$mysqli->prepare($selectedstudentqry);
// You only need to call bind_param once
$selectedstudentstmt->bind_param("i",$_POST["session"]);
// get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
$selectedstudentstmt->execute(); 
$selectedstudentstmt->bind_result($detailsStudentAlias,$detailsStudentForename,$detailsStudentSurname);
$selectedstudentstmt->store_result();
$selectedstudentnum = $selectedstudentstmt->num_rows();     

}else{  

$selectedstudentqry = "
SELECT
StudentAlias, StudentForename, StudentSurname
FROM
Student
WHERE
(StudentId = ?)
ORDER BY StudentAlias
";

global $mysqli;
$selectedstudentstmt=$mysqli->prepare($selectedstudentqry);
// You only need to call bind_param once
$selectedstudentstmt->bind_param("i",$_POST["student"]);
// get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
$selectedstudentstmt->execute(); 
$selectedstudentstmt->bind_result($detailsStudentAlias,$detailsStudentForename,$detailsStudentSurname);
$selectedstudentstmt->store_result();
$selectedstudentnum = $selectedstudentstmt->num_rows();    

}    


//QUERY 2: Question details depending on selected question(s)


if ($_POST['question'] == 'All'){

$selectedquestionqry = " SELECT q.QuestionNo, q.QuestionContent, o.OptionType, q.NoofAnswers, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT Answer
                    ORDER BY Answer
                    SEPARATOR ',' ) AS Answer, r.ReplyType, q.QuestionMarks
                    FROM Question q
                    LEFT JOIN Answer an ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId
                    LEFT JOIN Reply r ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId
                    LEFT JOIN Option_Table o ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId
                    WHERE SessionId = ?
                    GROUP BY q.QuestionId
                    ORDER BY q.QuestionId";
";

global $mysqli;
$selectedquestionstmt=$mysqli->prepare($selectedquestionqry);
// You only need to call bind_param once
$selectedstudentstmt->bind_param("i",$_POST["session"]);
// get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
$selectedquestionstmt->execute(); 
$selectedquestionstmt->bind_result($detailsQuestionNo,$detailsQuestionContent,$detailsOptionType,$detailsNoofAnswers,
$detailsAnswer,$detailsReplyType,$detailsQuestionMarks);
$selectedquestionstmt->store_result();
$selectedquestionnum = $selectedquestionstmt->num_rows(); 


}else{

$selectedquestionqry = "
SELECT q.QuestionNo, q.QuestionContent, o.OptionType, q.NoofAnswers, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT Answer
                    ORDER BY Answer
                    SEPARATOR ',' ) AS Answer, r.ReplyType, q.QuestionMarks
                    FROM Question q
                    LEFT JOIN Answer an ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId
                    LEFT JOIN Reply r ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId
                    LEFT JOIN Option_Table o ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId
                    WHERE QuestionId = ?
                    GROUP BY q.QuestionId
                    ORDER BY q.QuestionId
";

global $mysqli;
$selectedquestionstmt=$mysqli->prepare($selectedquestionqry);
// You only need to call bind_param once
$selectedquestionstmt->bind_param("i",$_POST["question"]);
// get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
$selectedquestionstmt->execute(); 
$selectedquestionstmt->bind_result($detailsQuestionNo,$detailsQuestionContent,$detailsOptionType,$detailsNoofAnswers,
$detailsAnswer,$detailsReplyType,$detailsQuestionMarks);
$selectedquestionstmt->store_result();
$selectedquestionnum = $selectedquestionstmt->num_rows(); 

}

//QUERY 3: Student Answers depending on selected student(s) and selected question(s)

$studentanswerqry = "
SELECT
sa.StudentId, sa.QuestionId, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT StudentAnswer ORDER BY StudentAnswer SEPARATOR ',') AS StudentAnswer, ResponseTime, MouseClick, StudentMark
FROM Student_Answer sa
INNER JOIN Student_Response sr ON sa.StudentId = sr.StudentId
WHERE
(sa.StudentId = ? AND sa.QuestionId = ?)
GROUP BY sa.StudentId, sa.QuestionId
";

global $mysqli;
$studentanswerstmt=$mysqli->prepare($studentanswerqry);
// You only need to call bind_param once
$studentanswerstmt->bind_param("ii",$_POST["student"], $_POST["question"]);
// get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
$studentanswerstmt->execute(); 
$studentanswerstmt->bind_result($detailsStudentAnswer,$detailsResponseTime,$detailsMouseClick,$detailsStudentMark);
$studentanswerstmt->store_result();
$studentanswernum = $studentanswerstmt->num_rows(); 


}

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iteratively build a `WHERE` clause. Consider that a `WHERE` clause does explicit filtering, so for cases where you're selecting "all" of something, you don't need to add any filters. The other filters build upon each other, so we can simply join them with `AND`s in the `WHERE`:

```
$query = 'SELECT ... FROM ...';

// Initially empty
$where = array();
$parameters = array();

// Check whether a specific student was selected
if($stu !== 'All') {
    $where[] = 'stu = ?';
    $parameters[] = $stu;
}

// Check whether a specific question was selected
// NB: This is not an else if!
if($ques !== 'All') {
    $where[] = 'ques = ?';
    $parameters[] = $ques;
}

// If we added to $where in any of the conditionals, we need a WHERE clause in
// our query
if(!empty($where)) {
    $query .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $where);
}

$result = prepare_and_execute_query($query, $parameters);
```

---

Okay, so looking at your update, you have a fairly complex set of queries, but it's possible to combine it into one statement. Give this a try:

```sql
SELECT
    s.StudentId, s.StudentAlias, s.StudentForename,         -- Student fields
    s.StudentSurname,
    q.QuestionId, q.QuestionNo, q.QuestionContent,          -- Question fields
    q.OptionType, q.NoofAnswers, q.Answer, q.ReplyType,
    q.QuestionMarks,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT sa.StudentAnswer ORDER BY         -- Answer fields
        sa.StudentAnswer SEPARATOR ',') AS StudentAnswer,
    sr.ResponseTime, sr.MouseClick, sr.StudentMark
FROM Student s
INNER JOIN Student_Answer sa ON (s.StudentId = sa.StudentId)
INNER JOIN Question q ON (sa.QuestionId = q.QuestionId)
INNER JOIN Student_Response sr ON (sa.StudentId = sr.StudentId)
WHERE                     -- This WHERE clause may be entirely removed, 
                          -- depending on the filters
    s.StudentId = ? AND   -- This is removed if $_POST['student'] is 'All'
    q.QuestionId = ?      -- This is removed if $_POST['question'] is 'All'
GROUP BY sa.StudentId, q.QuestionId
```

I think this will do what you want. I wasn't quite sure about which fields are part of `Student_Response` and which are part of `Student_Answer` so you might have to fiddle with the columns in the `SELECT`.

---

Unfortunately that approach doesn't work for your use case. But we can still consider how the original logic I proposed would work with one of your queries given:

```
$selectedstudentqry = "
SELECT
StudentAlias, StudentForename, StudentSurname
FROM
Student ";
if($_POST['student'] !== 'All') { // Check here
    $selectedstudentqry .= "
    WHERE
    (StudentId = ?) ";
}
$selectedstudentqry .= "
ORDER BY StudentAlias
";

global $mysqli;
$selectedstudentstmt=$mysqli->prepare($selectedstudentqry);
if($_POST['student'] !== 'All') {
    // You only need to call bind_param once
    $selectedstudentstmt->bind_param("i",$_POST["student"]);
}
// get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
$selectedstudentstmt->execute(); 
$selectedstudentstmt->bind_result($detailsStudentAlias,$detailsStudentForename,$detailsStudentSurname);
$selectedstudentstmt->store_result();
$selectedstudentnum = $selectedstudentstmt->num_rows();
```

Notice how we've simply moved the outer `if`s to more specific places within the code to decrease code duplication. If you see duplication like you have, there's a very good chance that you're doing something like making your conditionals too broad. You're definitely on the right track with trying to simplify this and reduce redundancy, though.

Comment: Can I Post you the queries I got now and the way I have filtered them and then can you edit your answer to match your solution with my queries?

Comment: Sure, although I feel it would benefit you more to try to figure it out for yourself. Maybe we can start with this: is there something in particular you're having trouble with while implementing this logic?

Comment: The problem I am having is that I have three queries. One query retrieves student details depending on student selected from drop down and second query retrieves question details depending on question chosen from drop down. The biggest issue is the third query which checks for student's answers, this query requires knowing which student has been selected (either one student or all students) and also which question selected (either one question or all questions) to check which question(s) we want to see a student's answer for.

Comment: Let me include and update with what I got at moment. if you can implement your solution for the third query, then I will be able to know to implement it for the other 2 queries.

Comment: I added a single query that I _think_ accomplishes everything your three queries were doing. See if you can work with it a bit -- it's kinda complex and I'm not exactly sure it's right.

Comment: Im not sure if the one query works. I want to display three seperate sets of details, student details, question details and student answer details, so I think I prefer separate queries depending on chosen filter. I tried your single query but I messed up because I got couple of queries incorrect, so it did not work. I updated the update to include the definite correct queries

Comment: Just imagine if you had a couple of drop down menus to filter your queries for STUDENT DETAILS, QUESTION DETAILS and STUDENT'S ANSWERS, how would you do it is what I am really asking

Comment: Gotcha. I think your best bet is to use your current logic then. You can still simplify your student and question details queries using the process that I described (notice that in the student details queries, the only difference between them is that the second one has a `WHERE` clause added -- you can isolate the `if` statement to just that clause). I'll add another quick example for that.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful :), Just need to ask you one little question in your update, if I select the `All` option, will the query output student details for all Students displayed in the drop down only or would it display every single student in the db details? If it is the latter then how can it be written to include WHERE clause for `WHERE (SessionId = ?)` if user selects `All`, else do the other where clause `   WHERE
    (StudentId = ?) `.

Comment: The SessionId = ? means it limits to only find students taking that exam (session)

Comment: My example won't take into account the `SessionId`, but you can easily support it by adding `else` statements to the `if`s.

Answer (score 0):

This is code I used where there are 64 permutations of user input. There can be a rider ID from another page, partial first and/or last name, a year, a month or a course ID.

Construct part of the where clause with a variety of ANDs, IS LIKE, etc.

```
$params = array();
$types = "";


if ( isset($_GET["riderid"]) && $_GET["riderid"] )  {
    $where = sprintf (' AND %s.id = ?', $tables["rider"]);
    $params[]= $_GET["riderid"];
    $types = $types .'i';

} else {
    if ( isset($_GET["last"]) && $_GET["last"] ) {

        $where = sprintf(' AND %s.last like ?', $tables["rider"]);
        $params[] = $_GET["last"] . "%";
        $types = $types . "s";
    }

    if ( isset($_GET["first"]) && $_GET["first"] ) {

        $whereFirst = sprintf(' AND %s.first like ?', $tables["rider"]);
        $where = $where . $whereFirst;
        $params[] = $_GET["first"] . "%";
        $types = $types . "s";
    }
}

if ( isset($_GET["year"]) && $_GET["year"] && $_GET["year"] != -1 )  {
    $whereYear = sprintf(' AND YEAR(%s.date) = ?', $tables["race"]);
    $where = $where . $whereYear;
    $params[] = $_GET["year"];
    $types = $types . "i";
}

if ( isset($_GET["month"]) && $_GET["month"] && $_GET["month"] != -1 )  {
    $whereMonth = sprintf(' AND month(%s.date) = ?', $tables["race"]);
    $where = $where . $whereMonth;
    $params[] = $_GET["month"];
    $types = $types . "i";

}  

if ( isset($_GET["courseid"]) && $_GET["courseid"] && $_GET["courseid"] != -1 ) {
    $whereCourse = sprintf(' AND %s.courseid = ?', $tables["race"]);
    $where = $where . $whereCourse;
    $params[] = $_GET["courseid"];
    $types = $types . "i";
}
```

Here is the query.

```
    //
    // Show selected races
    //
    $listQuery = "SELECT {$tables["race"]}.raceid, {$tables["race"]}.typeid, " .
             "           tag,  {$tables["race"]}.date, " .
             "           {$tables["location"]}.name, {$tables["course"]}.dist, " .
             "           {$tables["course"]}.description,  " .
             "           {$tables["result"]}.time, {$tables["result"]}.dnf, " .
             "           {$tables["rider"]}.first, {$tables["rider"]}.last ".
             "  FROM {$tables["race"]}, {$tables["sysracetype"]}, " .
             "       {$tables["course"]}, {$tables["location"]}, " .
             "       {$tables["result"]}, {$tables["rider"]} " .
             " WHERE {$tables["race"]}.courseid = {$tables["course"]}.courseid " .
             "   AND {$tables["race"]}.typeid = {$tables["sysracetype"]}.typeid " .
             "   AND {$tables["course"]}.locid = {$tables["location"]}.locid " .
             "   AND {$tables["race"]}.raceid = {$tables["result"]}.raceid" .
             "   AND {$tables["result"]}.riderid = {$tables["rider"]}.id" .
             $where .
             $orderby;
```

Prepare and bind the parameters.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare ($db_connection, $listQuery);
// 
// Handle the varying number of SQL parameters / place holders.
// Push the first two parameter of mysqli_stmt_bind_param
//
$bindArgs = array ($stmt, $types);

//
// Change parameters to refs  (depends on PHP version)   
//
foreach ($params as $key => $value)  
    $bindArgs[] =& $params[$key];

//
// Use "call back" to pass all params.
//
call_user_func_array("mysqli_stmt_bind_param", $bindArgs);
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved a similar problem this way. Where $parmMap is constructed with powers of 2 (1,2) as I detect each optional WHERE clause item and append the appropriate AND fieldName = ?.

```
switch ($parmMap ) {
    case 0:
      break;
    case 1:
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param ($stmt, "i", $courseParm );
      break;
    case 2:
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param ($stmt, "i", $yearParm );
      break;
    case 3:
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param ($stmt, "ii", $courseParm, $yearParm );
      break;
    default:
      break;
}
```

I won't be using this though for another query that has six optional where clause conditions! I've discovered `call_user_func_array`.

Comment: The accepted answer only manages one or zero bound variables. I agree that my solution becomes unwieldy for more than a few optional `where` clause parms, but for two or three the code is readable. For more than that, as I suggested, an array is better.