# How to create a dynamic WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to create a dynamic WHERE clause where depending on which options are chosen from the drop down menus, it will compile the correct WHERE clause. But I do not think I am doing it correctly.

First of all there should be a default WHERE clause, no matter which option is selected from the drop down menus there should be a WHERE clause checking for selected `SessionId` so this should be `SessionId = ?`

Then depending on the options chosen from the drop down menus it will compile the other fields in the WHERE  clause. There are two drop down menus which are for `Students` and `Questions`. The possible outcomes are:

`Student selected != 'All'` : Add `StudentId` = ? in WHERE clause
`Student selected == 'All'` : Remove `StudentId` = ? from WHERE clause
`Question selected != 'All'` : Add `QuestionId` = ? in WHERE clause
`Question selected == 'All'` : Remove `QuestionId` = ? from WHERE clause

My question is that how can I set this up?

Below is what I have currently:

```
        if(isset($_POST['answerSubmit'])) // we have subbmited the third form
        {

    $selectedstudentanswerqry = "
    SELECT
    StudentAlias, StudentForename, StudentSurname, q.SessionId, QuestionNo, QuestionContent, o.OptionType, q.NoofAnswers, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT Answer
    ORDER BY Answer SEPARATOR ',' ) AS Answer, r.ReplyType, QuestionMarks, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT StudentAnswer ORDER BY StudentAnswer SEPARATOR ',') AS StudentAnswer, ResponseTime, MouseClick, StudentMark
    FROM Student s
    INNER JOIN Student_Answer sa ON (s.StudentId = sa.StudentId)
    INNER JOIN Student_Response sr ON (sa.StudentId = sr.StudentId)
    INNER JOIN Question q ON (sa.QuestionId = q.QuestionId)
    INNER JOIN Answer an ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId
    LEFT JOIN Reply r ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId
    LEFT JOIN Option_Table o ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId
    ";

    if ($_POST['student'] != 'All'){
    $selectedstudentanswerqry .= "
    WHERE (SessionId = ? AND StudentId = ?)
    ";
    }

    if ($_POST['question'] != 'All'){
    $selectedstudentanswerqry .= "
    WHERE (SessionId = ? AND QuestionId = ?)
    ";
    }

    $selectedstudentanswerqry .= "
    GROUP BY sa.StudentId, q.QuestionId
    ORDER BY StudentAlias, q.SessionId, QuestionNo
    ";

    global $mysqli;
    $selectedstudentanswerstmt=$mysqli->prepare($selectedstudentanswerqry);
    if ($_POST['student'] != 'All'){
    // You only need to call bind_param once
    $selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_param("ii",$_POST["session"],$_POST["student"]);
    }
    if ($_POST['question'] != 'All'){
    // You only need to call bind_param once
    $selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_param("ii",$_POST["session"],$_POST["question"]);
    }
    // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
    $selectedstudentanswerstmt->execute(); 
    $selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_result($detailsStudentAlias,$detailsStudentForename,$detailsStudentSurname,$detailsSessionId,$detailsQuestionNo, 
    $detailsQuestonContent,$detailsOptionType,$detailsNoofAnswers,$detailsAnswer,$detailsReplyType,$detailsQuestionMarks,$detailsStudentAnswer,$detailsResponseTime,
    $detailsMouseClick,$detailsStudentMark);
    $selectedstudentanswerstmt->store_result();
    $selectedstudentanswernum = $selectedstudentanswerstmt->num_rows();     

    }


    ?>
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code above?

Comment: @Roy It seems like it is produce 2 SessionId = ? in WHERE clause which is technically incorrect

Comment: [Please quit that thing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14305295/285587) of [deleting questions and asking it again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14538384/how-to-compile-where-clause-in-query-depending-on-which-options-chosen)

Comment: [...and again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14533388/is-there-a-shorter-way-to-set-up-queries-when-filtering-results)

Answer (score 4):

Try to build where array

```
$where = array();


if ((int) $studentID >0) {
   $where[] = " studentID = '{$studentID}' ";
}
if ((int) $QuestionId  >0) {
   $where[] = " QuestionId  = '{$QuestionId }' ";
}
```

and at end implode $where by AND statment

```
if (!empty($where)) 
$query['where'] = ' WHERE '. implode(' AND ', $where);
```

It's only a way. I did not debug this code.

Answer (score 0):

Your cases:

```
- Student selected != 'All' : Add StudentId = ? in WHERE clause 
- Student selected == 'All' : Remove StudentId = ? from WHERE clause 
- Question selected != 'All' : Add QuestionId = ? in WHERE clause 
- Question selected == 'All' : Remove QuestionId = ? from WHERE clause

<?php
$selectedstudentanswerqry = "WHERE SessionId = ? ";
if ($_POST['student'] != 'All'){
 $selectedstudentanswerqry .= " and StudentId = ? ";
}
else{
/*
$selectedstudentanswerqry .= "
//what is condition for if student == all ?
";
*/
}
if ($_POST['question'] != 'All'){
  $selectedstudentanswerqry .= " and QuestionId = ? ";
}
else{
}
?>
```

consider that

```
student = 1 then:

if student != All = true
if question != AA = true

student = All
if student != All = false
if question != AA = true

question = 1 
if student != All = true
if question != AA = true

question = All
if student != All = true
if question != AA = false
```

### check if you want this? I think no.

```
    //case1
    if ($_POST['student'] != 'All'){
      $selectedstudentanswerqry .= "
      WHERE (SessionId = ? AND StudentId = ?)
      ";
    }

    //case2
    if ($_POST['question'] != 'All'){
      //case 2.1
      if ($_POST['student'] != 'All'){
        $selectedstudentanswerqry .= "
         and  (QuestionId = ?)
        ";
      }
      //case 2.2
      else{
        $selectedstudentanswerqry .= "
        WHERE (SessionId = ? AND QuestionId = ?)
        ";
      }

    }
/*
    testing
    1- student != All, question != All
    case1: true
    case1: result: $selectedstudentanswerqry = WHERE (SessionId = ? AND StudentId = ?)
    case2 : true
    case 2.1: true
    case2.1 result:  $selectedstudentanswerqry .= and  (QuestionId = ?)

    2- student != All question = All
    case1: true
    case1: result: $selectedstudentanswerqry = WHERE (SessionId = ? AND StudentId = ?)
    case2: false

    3- student = All question != All
    case1: false
    case2: true
    case2.1: false
    case2.2: true
    case2.2 result: $selectedstudentanswerqry = WHERE (SessionId = ? AND QuestionId = ?)

    4- student = All question = All
    case1: false
    case2: false
*/
```

Comment: When voting down, its better to comment out why?!!!

Comment: If any of the options equals all then it does not include the where statement for that field becuase we are not looking for a specific student. Will that definetly add the `and StudentId = ?` and `and QuestionId` in the WHERE clause?

Comment: You see I want to wrap where clause in (). Thats my issue

Comment: upvote to get it back to 0 bte, I do not know who down voted it

Comment: Student selected == 'any' and Question selected == 'any' occurs together?!

Comment: Can you give me 15 mins to make and show a little demo of the drop down menus?

Comment: Ok, I will instead tell you what to do in the app. I just want you to see the filter drop down menus which are `Students` and `Questions` drop down menus, at least you know which possible options are selected. Follow these steps ...

Comment: ok got it. one of them can be selected (not both), if Student selected, the Question will be null (empty), lets go back to your logic, please update of my answer.

Comment: Here is app [Application](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/Text30.php). In the Assessments drop down menu, select an assessment, then submit and then you will see the `Students` and `Questions` drop down menu. User uses them two drop down menus to filter and then click on submit button underneath ( I have not included the submit button in the demo)

Comment: No, no it could be either: one student selected and all questions selected OR all students selected and one question selected OR one student selected and one question selected OR finally all students selected and all questions selected. they are the possible outcomes. But the WHERE clause should always have `SessionId = ?` (The assessment chosen)

Comment: I get it, based on that: you must not include "where" for both cases in your code because there is a case that both conditions are true, you need to deeper your logic. I will send my suggestion in my answer.

Comment: Ok can you implement your answer to fit my code, that is really what I am asking because its the implementation I am struggling with. I saw your last code snippet but is that correct because if the where clause is already closed with (), then doesn't `And Question = ?` make it `(SessionId = ? AND StudentId = ?) AND QuestionId = ?)`? You have got the query and mysqli code, now how would you code it to meet with the possible outcomes

Comment: please implement last code of my answer ( I updated ) it must work...

Comment: Wouldn't the `and QuestionId = ?` be placed outside the parenthesis look at case 2 when it should be placed inside? Also it doesn't look right still, looking at case 2 and case 2.1 shouldn't it be StudentId = ? and QuestionId = ?. Why can't we have SessionId = ? as default where clause?

Comment: can you test the last code for mine, lets see the result!

Comment: Sorry, been asleep, I will comment to you on the outcome, I need to output the details to test, I will let you know in the next hour