# Submit mysqli query only partly working

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to find a way in PHP to **combine data from several drop down boxes into one SQL statement**. I can get this to partly work. Here is the SQL query:

```
$sql = "
  SELECT *
  FROM books
  WHERE
    author = '$bird'
    AND genre = '$cat'
    AND year= '$mouse'
    AND publisher = '$goat'
";
```

`$bird`, `$cat` etc are the variables that hold the selection from each drop down box.
I am getting mixed results. **All four will work together fine and all will work individually**.

So If I select from authors, genre, year and publisher, then press select it works and if I select these individually they work as well.

But if try and just select two items, let's say author and year, **it does not work and can produce a variety of incorrect data**. Here is the complete code. Any help appreciated:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br>
        <form name="myform" action="authors3.php" method="POST">
            <select name="author" size="2">
            <option value="ken davies">ken davies</option>
            <option value= "arthur smith">arthur smith</option>
            <option value="gill rafferty">gill rafferty</option><br />
            <option value="molly brown">molly brown</option><br />
            <option value="gilbert riley">gilbert riley</option><br />
            <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "go">

            <select name="genre" size="4">
            <option value="adventure">adventure</option>
            <option value="biography">biography</option>
            <option value="crime">crime</option><br />
            <option value="romance">romance</option>
            <option value="thriller">thriller</option>
            <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "go">

            <select name="year" size="4">
            <option value="2002">2002</option>
            <option value="2003">2003</option>
            <option value="2004">2004</option>
            <option value="2005">2005</option>
            <option value="2006">2006</option>
            <option value="2007">2007</option>
            <option value="2008">2008</option>
            <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "go">

            <select name="publisher" size="4">
            <option value="blue parrot">blue parrot</option>
            <option value="yonkers">yonkers</option>
            <option value="zoot">zoot</option>
            <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "go">

                <?php
                    $bird = (!empty($_POST['author'])) ? $_POST['author'] : null;
                    $cat = (!empty($_POST['genre'])) ? $_POST['genre'] : null;
                    $mouse = (!empty($_POST['year'])) ? $_POST['year'] : null;
                    $goat = (!empty($_POST['publisher'])) ? $_POST['publisher'] : null;

                    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
                    If (!$con) {
                        die("Can not Connect with database" .  mysql_error());
                    }
                    mysql_select_db("authors",$con);


                    if (isset($bird) && isset($cat) && isset($mouse) && isset($goat)){  
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE author = '$bird'
                                AND genre = '$cat' AND year = '$mouse' AND
                                publisher = '$goat' ";
                    }
                    else if (isset($bird)) { 
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE author = '$bird' ";
                    }
                    else if (isset($cat)) {
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE genre = '$cat' ";
                    }
                    else if (isset($mouse)) {   
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE year = '$mouse' ";    
                    }       
                    else if (isset($goat)) {
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE publisher = '$goat' ";    
                    }   

                    $myData = mysql_query($sql,$con);

                    echo"<table border=1>

                    <tr>
                        <th>id</th>
                        <th>author</th>
                        <th>title</th>
                        <th>publisher</th>
                        <th>year</th>
                        <th>genre</th>
                        <th>sold</th>
                    </tr>";

                    while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>" . $record['id'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $record['author'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $record['title'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $record['publisher'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $record['year'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $record['genre'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $record['sold'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<tr />";
                    }
                    echo "</table>";

                    mysql_close($con);
                ?>
                note: all four are working<br />
                all work individually<br />
                two or three dont work together
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to make each part of the where clause conditional if it is not required. Right now if they don't select genre for example your select is something like `WHERE author = 'x' AND genre = '' (or nothing?) AND ...` where you needed I'm guessing `WHERE author = 'x' AND year ...`. Depending on your need, if a combo is unselected, you need to fill in a wildcard to make it `AND genre = '%'...` to allow ANY genre.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14540135/how-to-create-a-dynamic-where-clause

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that you're using a deprecated way connecting to MySQL (read up on SQL injection and PDO), you're not covering all the use cases in your code.

A better way might be to write a base query (`$q = 'SELECT * FROM books WHERE`), and extend that query with the appropriate extra WHERE clauses, based on checking if the parameter is empty or not (`if (!empty($goat)) // append new clause to the WHERE portion`).

Answer (score 0):

You're query is half fine. Your declarations are the cause of your problem! The reason is you're essentially doing this:

```
genre ='adventure' and year = null.
```

What you want to do is edit your query accordingly. So you'll want to do

```
if (!is_null($year)) {

     $sql.= "AND Year = $year";

}
```

Problem is the above method allows injection!! Which if you're fessed about is a BIG PROBLEM!!!!

So I would recommend using bind_params BUT having said that calling cal_user_func_array on bind_params is a bit tricky so I'd recommend using PDO where you can edit your query and manage your parameters safely and effectively