# Multiple option search from database using single query

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

```
$data1=$_REQUEST['data1'];
$data2=$_REQUEST['data2'];
$data3=$_REQUEST['data3'];

mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT pu.id, monthname(pu.date_complete) AS Month 
       FROM `pds_user` pu 
     WHERE monthname(pu.date_complete) IN ('".implode("','",$data1)."') 
     AND pu.date_complete IN ('".implode("','",$data2)."') 
     AND Name IN ('".implode("','",$data3)."')
     ORDER BY Month");
```

If $data1 is empty, what to do?

Comment: check !empty() then create dynamic where clause

Comment: how to create dynamic where clause?

Comment: @Smritimay Debnath fetch the data from  `$data` if this is empty than ...... you can use `PHP empty()`  function

Comment: have a look at this [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14540135/how-to-create-a-dynamic-where-clause ]

Comment: actually, if $data1 is empty then i want full table data.. is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `!empty` then create dynamic `where clause`

```
    $where_clause ='where 1=1';

    if(!empty($data1))
    {
       $where_clause .= " And monthname(pu.date_complete) IN ('".implode("','",$data1)."')"; 
    }

    if(!empty($data2))
    {
       $where_clause .= " And pu.date_complete IN ('".implode("','",$data2)."') "; 
    }

    if(!empty($data3))
    {
       $where_clause .= " And Name IN ('".implode("','",$data3)."')"; 
    }

    mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT pu.id, monthname(pu.date_complete) AS Month 
                    FROM `pds_user` pu $where_clause  ORDER BY Month");
```

Comment: thank's it works for me.and please change syntax if(!empty($data1)) $data2, $data3 respectivly...

Comment: oh nice catch .glad to help you @SmritimayDebnath