# How to create a mysqli dynamic WHERE clause

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have an application here: [Application](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/Text30.php)

The application is there to show you the two drop down menus I want to use as a filter to be able to get Student's Answers determining on the student(s) selected and the question(s) selected form the respective drop down menus.

To see the drop down menus, in the application select an `Assessment` from the `Assessment` drop down menu and submit, you will see the students and questions drop down menus displayed underneath.

Now what I want to do is to create a dynamic WHERE clause depending on the options selected from the student(s) and question(s) drop down menus when the user clicked on the `Get Student Answers` button.

Below is the current query. The query has to have the default clause `SessionId =  ?` at all times in the WHERE clause. The other clauses `studentId = ?` and `questionId = ?`depends on the options the user
 has chose from both drop downs.

```
$selectedstudentanswerqry = "
SELECT
StudentAlias, q.SessionId, QuestionNo, QuestionContent, o.OptionType, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT Answer
ORDER BY Answer SEPARATOR ',' ) AS Answer, r.ReplyType, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT StudentAnswer ORDER BY StudentAnswer SEPARATOR ',') AS StudentAnswer, ResponseTime
FROM Student s
INNER JOIN Student_Answer sa ON (s.StudentId = sa.StudentId)
INNER JOIN Student_Response sr ON (sa.StudentId = sr.StudentId)
INNER JOIN Question q ON (sa.QuestionId = q.QuestionId)
INNER JOIN Answer an ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId
LEFT JOIN Reply r ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId
LEFT JOIN Option_Table o ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId
WHERE (SessionId = ?)
GROUP BY sa.StudentId, q.QuestionId
ORDER BY StudentAlias, q.SessionId, QuestionNo
";

global $mysqli;
$selectedstudentanswerstmt=$mysqli->prepare($selectedstudentanswerqry);
// You only need to call bind_param once
$selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_param("i",$_POST["session"]);
// get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
$selectedstudentanswerstmt->execute(); 
$selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_result($detailsStudentAlias,$detailsSessionId,$detailsQuestionNo, 
$detailsQuestonContent,$detailsOptionType,$detailsAnswer,$detailsReplyType,$detailsStudentAnswer,$detailsResponseTime);
$selectedstudentanswerstmt->store_result();
$selectedstudentanswernum = $selectedstudentanswerstmt->num_rows();
```

Below is the Students and Questions drop down menus as a sample html:

**Students Drop Down Menu:**

```
<select name="student" id="studentsDrop">
<option value="All">All</option>
<option value="3">u0499220 - Jack Briggs</option>
<option value="7">u0093220 - Mary Kay</option>
</form>
```

**Questions Drop Down Menu:**

```
<select name="question" id="questionsDrop">
<option value="All">All</option>
<option value="34">1</option>
<option value="35">2</option>
<option value="36">3</option>
</form>
```

I am thinking of something like if a specific student is selected then include `StudentId = ?` in WHERE clause, if specific question number is selected then include `QuestionId = ?` in WHERE clause. But if the `All` value is selected in Student drop down menu then remove `StudentId = ?` from the WHERE clause as we are look for all student, not whittling down for a specific student. This is same for if `All` value is selected from Question drop down menu but obviously dealing with `QuestionId = ?`

Comment: Please quit that thing of [deleting questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14538384/how-to-compile-where-clause-in-query-depending-on-which-options-chosen) and then [asking it again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14533388/is-there-a-shorter-way-to-set-up-queries-when-filtering-results) and [again](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14540135/285587)

Answer (score 0):

Did you know that you can write a subquery here?

```
WHERE (SessionId = ?)
```

like

```
WHERE SessionId IN(SELECT SessionId FROM ...)
```

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/subqueries_part_1.html

Comment: Do I really need a subquery? I tested my query with what I have and added the where clause for StudentId and QuestionId by hand and set it to example ids and they worked fine. My issue is simply creating a dynamic where clause depending on which options are chosen. If you can expand your code showing what you are trying to achieve then it will be easier for me to understand what you are saying. But it will be nice if it can be done with a dynamic where clause because I am already using JOINS to join tables

Comment: Maybe the situation could be modified a little to use a CASE statement instead. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html

Comment: So a case statement on all possibilities between the two drop down menus and displaying the WHERE clause for each case? Is that the best way doing it? If you think that is then please provide a sample on how you would write the case statement. DOn't have to write whole case statement but want to see how you would list the possibilities from the drop down menus

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you know what? I think I have misunderstood the real question here. You may find this to work better:

```
    $selectedstudentanswerqry = "
    SELECT
    StudentAlias, q.SessionId, QuestionNo, QuestionContent, o.OptionType, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT Answer
    ORDER BY Answer SEPARATOR ',' ) AS Answer, r.ReplyType, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT StudentAnswer ORDER BY StudentAnswer SEPARATOR ',') AS StudentAnswer, ResponseTime
    FROM Student s
    INNER JOIN Student_Answer sa ON (s.StudentId = sa.StudentId)
    INNER JOIN Student_Response sr ON (sa.StudentId = sr.StudentId)
    INNER JOIN Question q ON (sa.QuestionId = q.QuestionId)
    INNER JOIN Answer an ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId
    LEFT JOIN Reply r ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId
    LEFT JOIN Option_Table o ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId";

    if (studentId = something && questionId = something) {

    $selectedstudentanswerqry .= "WHERE (SessionId = ?)
    GROUP BY sa.StudentId, q.QuestionId
    ORDER BY StudentAlias, q.SessionId, QuestionNo
    ";

    } else if (studentId = somethingelse && questionId = somethingelse) {

    $selectedstudentanswerqry .= "WHERE (SessionId = ?)
    GROUP BY sa.StudentId, q.QuestionId
    ORDER BY StudentAlias, q.SessionId, QuestionNo
    ";

    } else {
    $selectedstudentanswerqry .= "WHERE (SessionId = ?)
    GROUP BY sa.StudentId, q.QuestionId
    ORDER BY StudentAlias, q.SessionId, QuestionNo
    ";
    }
```

Comment: I will have to go for this way. Luckily I only have 2 drop down menus so I can get a way with it. But before I mark your answer, just comment to me the way you would have coded it if there was 5 or 6 drop down menus, would you go with case statement and check all 5 - 6 options? This is why I was asking the best way because I like a practical solution which could work no matter is there is 2 drop down menus or 6 drop down menus, this is to help other people who may see this question

Comment: Actually, yeah, the case statement would be the equivalent. I edited the answer above to show that at the end you may finish with an 'else' clause, however, if you use the case statement you will have the 'default' clause.

Comment: I still think there could be an elegant solution to it somehow within the where clause that either a nested select could be used or a case statement. Since the idea is a little complicated to me and I don't have the full table structure, I suggested a php way that would allow for much more dynamic interaction. Unfortunately, MySQL is a much less dynamic world where writing a query can sometimes be very complicated.

Comment: i don't mind doing it php structure, but I need you to be able to code it as I have never done it before. If I am able to show you the table structure would you think you will be able to do it?